# How to keep sort order in WPF Datagrid, when toggling child controls

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a Window with a Border control inside.

The Border is a placeholder for different views/user controls.

First view is a user control with a data grid.
The data grid works fine.
I can sort columns by clicking column header.

Than I exchange the borders child with another user control for different use case.
This works also fine.

When I now exchange the border child back to the first data grid user control,
my sorting got lost.

Lets say the second column was sorted descending before switching,
than the first column is sorted ascending when I switch back to it.

I am caching the data grid user control, which means, I do not destroy it and create a new one.

So how can I keep my sort order when switching back to it?

Comment: Have you considered using a tabcontrol? It seems like what you want to use.

Comment: I have a tab control in another UI area. This is used as a trigger to switch the view, so it doesn't contain the view. This is the given UI layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

Instead of unsing a Border control and exchanging the Borders Child, I will use a StackPanel.
When the view has to be "switched" I "collapse" (a term of WPF visiblity enums) the old view and make the new view visible.

When toggling back I do it vice versa.

Thus the parent/child relationship is kept and all sort orders and selection states are kept.

Comment: You could have used as I said, a tabcontrol just with the header turned off and then you just set the index and you wouldn't have to do all of the visibility work.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.
As said the tab control is NOT containing the views.
It is just used as a trigger to switch the view.

This is due to the given layout of the ui.
The Tab control is not directly above the views and I cannot move it.

Therefore my question.

Comment: you said the border contained the controls, now you are saying it doesn't?  Next time actually show some xaml because you are being confusing.

Comment: I said A border control contained the controls.
This was the first solution. which didn't work, because i switched the child control inside the border by exchanging the child.
That lead to the problem that the sorting wasn't kept.

The tab control we had, never had a border inside.
It was only used for a trigger to switch the child within the border control which ist NOT part of the tabcontrol.

NOW I introduced a StackPanel INSTEAD of the Border.
When toggling the tab I am now collapsing the one view inside StackPanel and set the other to visible and vice versa.

The tab conn

Comment: I never said something different.